# Python / pandas function to replace '-' negative sign but not negative sign in negative numbers ( '-' in '-1')

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a pandas  dataframe that contains - in missing value,
If I use `.replace('-','NaN')` it replaces -1 with NaN1
how can I remove only - sign but not - if its -1

Dataframe Example

```
Co1_1 Values
Pine  -
Apple -1
Mango 2
Berry -
Banana -3
```

Here I want to replace - in Pine & Berry not in banana

Comment: Try `df['col'].str.replace(r'-(?=\d)', '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for `.replace()` at all. Find the cells that contain the dash, and update them:

```
df[df['Values'] == '-'] = np.nan
```

Bear in mind that `'NaN'` is **not** a NaN: it is a string that looks like a NaN. A "real" NaN is `np.nan` from numpy.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the value of the column as numeric. Then maybe `-` will be replaces by `0`, not sure if you want it :

```py
pandas.to_numeric(arg, errors='raise', downcast=None)
```

[Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas-to-numeric)

---

If it doesn't work, `astype` may be an alternative

```py
DataFrame.astype(dtype, copy=True, errors='raise')
# Example :
df.astype({'values': int})
```

[Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html#pandas-dataframe-astype)

---

Nevertheless the most elegant solution, and the most often used is to use th pandas selector:

```py
df[ df['Values'] == '-' ] = np.nan
```

Also you can choose to replace the value `-` by anything you want: `0`,
`Nan` (np.nan), etc.

Answer (score -2):

So, if you first evaluate the length of the value you are going to check (converted to a string), than you could be sure to only select the '-' entries, when you just delete entries with length of one.

```
for values:
    if len(str(value)) == 1:
        value.replace(...)
```

But I'm shure there is a more elegant way ;D

Comment: This is not even valid Python.